Flex-column PrimeVue issue
I just started using PrimeVue and encountered a silly problem. I can't figure out why the flexbox class isn't working. I'm following the documentation exactly and trying to display an input with hints, but the elements are aligning in a row instead of stacking on top of each other. What am I doing wrong?
Here's the import code.

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import 'primevue/resources/themes/mdc-dark-indigo/theme.css'

import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext';


const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(PrimeVue)
app.use(router)

app.component('InputText', InputText)


app.mount('#app')


Here's the component code.
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref } from 'vue';

const value = ref(null);

</script>


<template>
  <div class="flex flex-column gap-2">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <InputText id="username" v-model="value" aria-describedby="username-help" />
    <small id="username-help">Enter your username to reset your password.</small>
</div>
</template>

I tried adding this import, but it didn't help.
import 'primevue/resources/primevue.min.css'

The flex classes are actually part of a separate utility library called PrimeFlex you'll need to install:
npm install primeflex

Then import the CSS in main.js or main.ts
import 'primeflex/primeflex.css'

